# Push an object with a property to an array

Tags: javascript

How can I do this in one line:

```
var u = { code: 'foo' };
var a = [];
var o = {};
o[u.code] = 'bar';
a.push(o);
```

The following, which I would have assumed to work, are invalid:

```
a.push({ u.code: 'bar' });
a.push({ u['code']: 'bar' });
```

I may be just having a brainfart here...

Comment: Like this: `var u = { code: 'foo' };var a = [];var o = {};o[u.code] = 'bar';a.push(o);` ... it's perfectly valid to have multiple statements in one line.

Comment: Javascript keys to object literals must always be string literals.

Comment: @Andrew: No, you can also use number literals and identifier names. https://es5.github.io/#x11.1.5

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg: `{ [key expression]: value expression }` [is planned for ES6](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:object_literals#object_literal_computed_property_keys)/https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object-initializer.

Comment: @false: ES6 https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object-initializer

Comment: Thanx @FelixKling I removed my answer....

Comment: @FelixKling: Huh, I ended up linking to the exact same thing.

Comment: @FelixKling, yes, but they are converted to strings.

Comment: Neat! I didn't know that about ES6.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg: True, the resulting value is converted to a string at *runtime*. But the *syntax* allows number literals and identifier names. I thought we talk about syntax here.

Comment: @FelixKling I was being a bit sloppy with my words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest you can make the code in ES5 is:

```
var u = { code: 'foo' }, a = [{}];
a[0][u.code] = 'bar';
```

Once [computed properties](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object-initializer) are supported by browsers (coming in ES6), you can use:

```
var u = { code: 'foo' }, a = [{[u.code]: 'bar'}];
```

You can also use ES6 syntax today and [transpile](https://www.npmjs.org/package/es6-computed-properties) it to ES5.

Answer (score 0):

Felix Kling's answer is **totally correct**, though there's a dirty alternative to do what you want in just one line (Don't tell anyone I told you to do this kind of thing =P):

```
a.push(JSON.parse('{"{0}": "bar"}'.replace('{0}', u.code)))
```